# UK Tier 4 student visa for Erasmus Mundus Scholarship receivers - scholarship amount is enough to show sufficient funding

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, uk-visa, students

I am a citizen of Tajikistan, currently finishing my undergraduate degree in Istanbul, Turkey.

I was accepted into the Erasmus Mundus Scholarship for 1 year in England/ **Birmingham** and 1 year in Italy.

***Scholarship details***:
The scholarship covers: student participation costs (including the tuition fees, full insurance coverage
and any other mandatory costs related to student participation in the course); a contribution to student
travel; a subsistence allowance for the entire duration of the study
programme.

The scholarship amount is 35 000 Euro for 2 years.

**For studies in the UK: money that would be left in my pocket would be:
living expenses 1000 euro/ month for 12 months and 1000 euro/year for travel - in total 13000 Euro for studies in the UK.**

**I was wondering if only the scholarship letter would be enough to show my financial means, to apply for the UK visa?**